# How does a virtual function impact constructor

Tags: c++, class, initialization, aggregate, virtual

I am in the process creating a game and I have a problem. When I put in a “virtual” keyword to the function constructor just stops working:(

System Windows 11, C++23

Edit:
You can not use braces with a class that has virtual functions.
Is there a way to not generate a definition in parent class, but define in child class?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to initialize an object of the class `notworks` as an object of an aggregate. But when a virtual function is declared then the class is not an aggregate.

From the C++ 20 Standard (9.4.2 Aggregates)

> 1 An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 11) with
>
> (1.1) — no user-declared or inherited constructors (11.4.5),
>
> (1.2) — no private or protected direct non-static data members (11.9),
>
> **(1.3) — no virtual functions** (11.7.3), and
>
> (1.4) — no virtual, private, or protected base classes (11.7.2).

Comment: That is correct thank you! I s there a way to not generate a definition in parent class, but define in child class?

Comment: @avary You can declare a pure virtual function in the base class.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what that is?

Comment: @avary For example virtual void f() = 0;

Comment: If I have an array of type A a[]. for example a[0] = B() where b is child class of class A, and I want to  call a[0].foo(), will it call A::foo()?

Comment: or does it need to be a pointer to call B::foo()

Comment: @avary You may not declare an array of objects of the base class and then to store an object of a derived class. You need to read a book on C++. If you have some other questions then feel free to ask them at SO. Comments are not designed to ask questions.

Comment: Is there a way I could do something similar then?